# In Haxe switch/case, is there a way to mix a case 'xx': with the default:?

Tags: haxe

I like to use **switch/case** a lot but I've been wondering if it's possible to mix a default with a case in **Haxe** (version 2 or 3)?

This is an example of what I'm trying to achieve, except it doesn't compile:

```
switch(s) {
    case 'reset': trace("...");
    case 'stat','stats': trace("...");        // This compiles ok in case some people don't know
    case 'help', default: trace("...");       // This doesn't compile
}
```

Do you know if this possible? I sometimes would prefer it this way because even though it's equivalent to just using a default, the code is sometimes more precise to the reader this way (no ambiguity or confusion).

Comment: Put the common code in a function, and then call the function from `case 'help'` and `default:`.

Comment: According to http://haxe.org/manual/lf-pattern-matching-or.html, in Haxe 3 it's also possible to write `case 'stat' | 'stats':` instead of `case 'stat', 'stats'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just managed to figure out a working solution for **Haxe 3**. Unfortunately it doesn't compile in Haxe 2.10, the version that I'm using right now. (Edit: I found a way for Haxe 2, see the other answer below).

The documentation here (http://haxe.org/manual/lf-pattern-matching-introduction.html) says that that " *a _ pattern matches anything, so case _: is equal to default:* ".

So similarly to writing `case 'stat', 'stats':` I tried to write `case 'help', _:` and it compiles.

So a short for Haxe 3 is:

```
switch(s) {
    case 'reset': trace("...");
    case 'stat','stats': trace("...");
    case 'help', _: trace("...");
}
```

I compiled an example here : http://try.haxe.org/#A8D15

Comment: Also possible to write `case 'help' | _: trace("...");` in Haxe 3.

Comment: Big project started in 2011 and no real reason to port everything to Haxe 3 for now, since it works well. I think a lot of people are still using Haxe 2.10. Even though some new notations and simpler macros look exciting in Haxe 3 I see no imperious reasons to switch just yet. Would probably take a week or so to port, compile on servers, test etc.

Comment: I guess the reason they added this feature in Haxe 3 is because there was no easy way to do it in Haxe 2. So your question there is likely to be unfulfilled.

Comment: No actually I found a way for Haxe 2, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an easy way that will work with **Haxe 2.xx**:

```
switch(s) {
    case 'reset': trace("...");
    case 'stat','stats': trace("...");
    case 'help', s /*!default!*/: trace("...");
}
```

So for Haxe 2.xx, all we have to do is repeat the expression inside the switch inside the final case and it will match anything. I recommend adding a comment just after for readability.

Strangely enough, this notation won't compile in Haxe 3.